# Seaborn pairplot ValueError: max must be larger than min in range parameter

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am getting this error while plotting pairplot using seaborn library in Python. With reference to the previous questions asked on the same topic, I cleaned my data and verified if I have any null value,

```
train_data.isnull().values.any()
Out[91]: False

import seaborn as sns
sns.pairplot(train_data)
```

I am still getting this Value Error for a seaborn plot. I am not sure apart from cleaning data, what else we can do to avoid this error. Adding more information about the data, I have total 81 columns and around half a million rows. I dropped a row having all null values and not remaining data is null free. Now question is how to proceed with this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: @rickert I saw same error and suggested solution was to clean the data and get null free. I did clean and got free from null, still getting this error.

Comment: @yan you might have ran out of the memory and got this error. Slice the dataset and check if it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I received the same error. I would suggest you to work on several things. First, check if you have `string` data type and either convert it to `float` or not add for `pairplot`, slice up your dataset and then work in it. I actually mean, `dimensional reduction`. 81 columns may not be the best choice to experiment. As you mentioned you have half a million rows and 81 columns. First try on smaller dataset and then go for larger one. Seaborn plot sometimes fails to accommodate so many rows and columns on local systems. If you try on some cluster with larger RAM, it might work fine but this error is not new. Try working on

```
exp = test_data[0:10][:1000]
sns.pairplot(exp)
```

Before applying this, first remove all string columns and experiment only on `float` , `int` value columns. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ! I removed all strings and it worked. I was just wondering why some float values got converted to object type (strings) while cleaning.

Comment: It happends becuase you might have assigned default value of string instead of int.

Answer (score 14):

Your dataframe might have NaN values. Remove those rows or replace NaN with 0 and it should work.

Comment: @StephenRauch, you can replace NaN with say 0 as                             train_data = train_data.fillna(0).                                                                                           To drop NaN you can do train_data.dropna(inplace=True)

Answer (score 4):

You need removed all NaN values in oririn DataFrame. Use method *df.dropna()*

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, **df.fillna()** doesn't replace values with **NaN** in our dataframe. Kindly use the **df.replace(np.nan, your_value)** .